# Minecraft - Bukkit Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, ping, minecraft, bukkit

I tried to get MOTD of the remote server, but I can't get colors. When MOTD is colored, the plugin isn't working.
I know why, but I don't know how to resolve it.

```
public PingServer(String host, int port) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;

    try {
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        out.write(0xFE);

        int b;
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
        while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
            if (b != 0 && b > 16 && b != 255 && b != 23 && b != 24) {
                str.append((char) b);
            }
        }

        data = str.toString().split("§");
        data[0] = data[0].substring(1, data[0].length());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

According to the [specification](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping#Beta_1.8_to_1.3), the plugin will get response like this: `MOTD§ONLINEPLAYERS§MAXPLAYERS`, which should be split on `§` to get the different portions.  However, `§` is also used for [chat messages](http://wiki.vg/Chat#Old_system), and I'm not sure how to differentiate between the two.  How can I work around this?

Comment: Please specify a few examples and how they should be decoded.

Comment: Are you using an old MC version?  The [ping](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping) hasn't looked like that since 1.6.

Comment: No really. I'm using 1.8.8 and i can say this method is working well. Only colors... :( Do you have better idea?

Comment: Xan - OK, let's say Motd is §aLobby (Green title Lobby) and online player is 1 and max players are 50. 
Result: §aLobby§1§50
So split isn't working now because MOTD isn't data[0] but data[1] and MOTD isn't colored but looking like that: aLobby

Comment: Oh, you're performing a legacy server list ping.  You shouldn't do that, as it's designed for legacy clients and missing a lot of information (probably including colors).  See [the "Current" section of this article](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping#Current).  You don't need to split on `§` anymore, so the problem of embedded color codes won't exist anymore (it'll be properly stored in a JSON blob).

Comment: @Pokechu22 - Thank you! It working! You can write it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently using the [legacy server list ping](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping#Beta_1.8_to_1.3), designed for **beta** 1.8 to 1.3.  That one is triggered via sending just `FE` to the server.  While current servers still support this ping, it's very old and has several flaws (including the one you found).

You should instead perform the [current ping](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping#Current).  While this is slightly more complicated, you don't need to implement much of the protocol to actually perform it.

There's only one complicated portion of the protocol you need to know about: `VarInt`s.  These are somewhat complicated because they take a varying number of bytes depending on the value.  And as such, you have a packet length that can be somewhat hard to calculate.

```
/** See http://wiki.vg/Protocol_version_numbers.  47 = 1.8.x */
private static final int PROTOCOL_VERSION_NUMBER = 47;
private static final int STATUS_PROTOCOL = 1;
private static final JsonParser PARSER = new JsonParser();

/** Pings a server, returning the MOTD */
public static String pingServer(String host, int port) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;

    try {
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

        byte[] hostBytes = host.getBytes("UTF-8");
        int handshakeLength =
                varIntLength(0) + // Packet ID
                varIntLength(PROTOCOL_VERSION_NUMBER) + // Protocol version number
                varIntLength(hostBytes.length) + hostBytes.length + // Host
                2 + // Port
                varIntLength(STATUS_PROTOCOL);  // Next state

        writeVarInt(handshakeLength, out);
        writeVarInt(0, out);  // Handshake packet
        writeVarInt(PROTOCOL_VERSION_NUMBER, out);
        writeVarInt(hostBytes.length, out);
        out.write(hostBytes);
        out.write((port & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        out.write(port & 0xFF);
        writeVarInt(STATUS_PROTOCOL, out);

        writeVarInt(varIntLength(0));
        writeVarInt(0);  // Request packet (has no payload)

        int packetLength = readVarInt(in);
        int payloadLength = readVarInt(in);
        byte[] payloadBytes = new int[payloadLength];
        int readLength = in.read(payloadBytes);
        if (readLength < payloadLength) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected end of stream");
        }
        String payload = new String(payloadBytes, "UTF-8");

        // Now you need to parse the JSON; this is using GSON
        // See https://github.com/google/gson
        // and http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0
        JsonObject element = (JsonObject) PARSER.parse(payload);
        JsonElement description = element.get("description");
        // This is a naive implementation; it assumes a specific format for the description
        // rather than parsing the entire chat format.  But it works for the way the
        // notchian server impmlements the ping.
        String motd = ((JsonObject) description).get("text").getAsString();

        return motd;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static int varIntLength(int value) {
    int length = 0;
    do {
        // Note: >>> means that the sign bit is shifted with the rest of the number rather than being left alone
        value >>>= 7;
        length++;
    } while (value != 0);
}

public static void writeVarInt(int value, OutputStream out) {
    do {
        byte temp = (byte)(value & 0b01111111);
        // Note: >>> means that the sign bit is shifted with the rest of the number rather than being left alone
        value >>>= 7;
        if (value != 0) {
            temp |= 0b10000000;
        }
        out.write(temp);
    } while (value != 0);
}
public static int readVarInt(InputStream in) {
    int numRead = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int read;
    do {
        read = in.read();
        if (read < 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected end of stream");
        }
        int value = (read & 0b01111111);
        result |= (value << (7 * numRead));

        numRead++;
        if (numRead > 5) {
            throw new RuntimeException("VarInt is too big");
        }
    } while ((read & 0b10000000) != 0);

    return result;
}
```

The current ping does use JSON, which means you need to use GSON.  Also, this implementation makes some assumptions about the [chat](http://wiki.vg/Chat) format; this implementation could break on custom servers that implement chat more completely, but it'll work for servers that embed `§` into the motd instead of using the more complete chat system (this includes the Notchian server implementation).

---

If you *need* to use the legacy ping, you can assume that the 2nd-to-last `§` marks the end of the MOTD (rather than the 1st `§`).  Something like this:

```
String legacyPingResult = str.toString();
String[] data = new String[3];
int splitPoint2 = legacyPingResult.lastIndexOf('§');
int splitPoint1 = legacyPingResult.lastIndexOf('§', splitPoint2 - 1);

data[0] = legacyPingResult.substring(0, splitPoint1);
data[1] = legacyPingResult.substring(splitPoint1 + 1, splitPoint2);
data[2] = legacyPingResult.substring(splitPoint2 + 1);
```

However, I still don't recommend using the legacy ping.